# dynamic variables from JSON object or strings in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json, server, dynamic-variables

I have a networked app that updates multiple parameters in real time by pushing an array of floats to the client. I want to be able to easily modify the mapping of the array of floats onto pre-existing variables in the client script each time I boot the server (by changing a JSON file for example)

On connection to the server, the client receives a list of parameters:

```
["delayTime", "feedbackAmount", "backgroundColor"]
```

Future message:

```
[0.01, 0.4, 0.9]
```

makes the variables of the same name equal:

```
delayTime = 0.01;
feedbackAmount = 0.4;
backgroundColor = 0.9;
```

Can I convert these strings/object keys into their associated variables and have the corresponding array of floats update them without designating the destination on each message (since the changing floats are coming through as fast as the server can send them)? By analogy...if it were just corresponding values of two arrays:

```
for (int i = 0; i < floatArray.length; i++){
     variable[i] = floatArray[i]
}
```

But the value of variable[i] is updating the associated variable that I've initialized.

I hope this makes sense; I can't wrap my brain around it but it seems like it should be fairly simple.

Comment: have you tried this https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_stringify.asp

Comment: @DarshanDave I kind of want to do the opposite – convert strings into variables (or rather, use them to associate with existing variables in the client script)

Comment: okay, means you have {key:value} as string and this you need as a variable correct

Comment: that you can do by Json.Parse

Answer (score 0):

Don't go that way, create another Array that contains objects like below.

```
[
    {
        "key": "delayTime",
        "value": 0.01
    },
    {
        "key": "feedbackAmount",
        "value": 0.4
    },
    {
        "key": "backgroundColor",
        "value": 0.9
    }
]
```

**MAP two array**

```
let a = ["delayTime", "feedbackAmount", "backgroundColor"];
let b = [0.01, 0.4, 0.9];
let tempArray;
tempArray = a.map(function (x, i) {
    return {"key": x, "value": b[i]}        
}.bind(this));
console.log(tempArray);
```